# Process columns in bash

Tags: bash

I would like to substitute characters in even columns with a different char, like this (with space):

**In**:

```
hello
```

**Out:**

```
h l o
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat readme.txt | sed -e "s/\(.\)./\1 /g"
```

EDIT: I noticed the slashes is hidden unless I used code style. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=length;i+=2) printf("%c ", substr($0, i, 1)); printf "\n"}' <filename>
```

awk processes each line in turn, the for loop processes every other character and prints it followed by a space

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/(.)./\1 /g'
```

I may be missing backslashes for the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Use extended regex option in `sed`:

`sed -r 's;(.).;\1 ;g' input-file`